# React запуск на vps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vps, react-router, nextjs

Где открывается порт открытый на vps?
в этой папки gameyg.ru/35/my-app,создала приложение React с помощью create-app
потом запустил, npm run build, npm start
Пишет, что отрыл приложение на 3000 порту, но https://5.181.109.116:3000/ или gameyg.ru/35/my-app ничего не открывается.
мне бы хотелось, чтобы сервер всё время открывался тут gameyg.ru/35/my-app[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все же четко написано, сервер поднят на localhost:3000
5.181.109.116 - совсем не локалхост) Возможно, вам стоит установить что-то вроде nginx и в качестве пути к директории сервера, указать папку build с собранным проектом.

Comment: Добавлю, для некста нужен proxy_pass если речь идет про nginx (проксирование запросов).